# runtime output objc[69590] when using CocoaPods with 2 projects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, multi-project

I created 2 xcode projects "mylib" and "myapp"

- the project type of mylib is "iOS -> **Cocoa Touch Framework**"
- and the project type of myapp is "iOS -> Application -> **Single View Application**".

Both of the projects depend on "AFNetworking", so I wrote the Podfile below.

```
workspace 'myapp'

platform :ios,'7.0'
xcodeproj 'myapp/myapp.xcodeproj'

target :myapp do
    xcodeproj 'myapp/myapp.xcodeproj'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'
end

target :mylib do
    xcodeproj 'mylib/mylib.xcodeproj'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'
end
```

After I run "pod install", I got https://github.com/everettjf/cocoapods_two_projects_obj69272 , and build without errors.

But when I run in the "iOS simulator" , lots of warning messages outputs in the console window.

```
objc[69590]: Class AFHTTPRequestOperation is implemented in both /Users/everettjf/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-exzydcmjfladtpgxcrxfchlkcmux/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib.framework/mylib and /Users/everettjf/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/409F22C7-031F-495C-BE66-EE4712D0D469/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A94992B7-C057-4842-9B64-D8B8E2E5E4DE/myapp.app/myapp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[69590]: Class AFHTTPRequestOperationManager is implemented in both /Users/everettjf/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-exzydcmjfladtpgxcrxfchlkcmux/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib.framework/mylib and /Users/everettjf/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/409F22C7-031F-495C-BE66-EE4712D0D469/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A94992B7-C057-4842-9B64-D8B8E2E5E4DE/myapp.app/myapp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[69590]: Class AFHTTPSessionManager is implemented in both /Users/everettjf/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-exzydcmjfladtpgxcrxfchlkcmux/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib.framework/mylib and /Users/everettjf/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/409F22C7-031F-495C-BE66-EE4712D0D469/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A94992B7-C057-4842-9B64-D8B8E2E5E4DE/myapp.app/myapp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[69590]: Class AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager is implemented in both /Users/everettjf/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-exzydcmjfladtpgxcrxfchlkcmux/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib.framework/mylib and /Users/everettjf/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/409F22C7-031F-495C-BE66-EE4712D0D469/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A94992B7-C057-4842-9B64-D8B8E2E5E4DE/myapp.app/myapp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
...(more)
```

How could I fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: create pod separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found 2 solutions.

1. solution 1

   mylib -> TARGETS(mylib) -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Mach-O Type : Static Library
2. solution 2

   just add "use_frameworks!" to Podfile

More information , please see [here](https://github.com/everettjf/cocoapods_two_projects_obj69272)

Comment: Not working with Swift. Do you have any knowledge of a solution for Swift projects?

Answer (score 0):

create pod separately for both projects.

use this  link to refer: http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2

Comment: Thanks , but is there any other way ?